# Hybrid Graphics Functional won't work with my Asus UL30V anymore

Tags: 12.04, hybrid-graphics

The problem is that I am no longer able to boot in compatibility mode for just turning on my Nvidia graphics to install the driver. Because no login screen will appear if Ubuntu is loading.

In Ubuntu 11.10 I was able to activate nvidia graphics only' option this way:

1) Change BIOS to 'compatibility mode' which will turn off the Intel card.

2) Install the Nvidia proprietary driver using Ubuntu's driver finder (Additional Drivers) and then reboot.

I was not interested using only the Intel graphics, for the sake of battery life. Now I have both cards running and they drain my battery life dramatically. And the main problem of this configuration no OpenGL is available, so I can't play any games any more.

At this point, I have a pre-solution. I uninstalled the nvidia drivers and installed bumblebee. Now the Intel card is recognized. I would prefer to run just the nvidia card as in Ubuntu 11.10 but for now this is better than nothing. Does anybody else have the same problem?

Comment: Could it be that you've used a script that switches to the nvidia card on boot? I recall machines where this was the case, but I'm not sure if it was actually the Asus UL30V.

Comment: No I didn't used a script at all. If there is a script I could use for this problem I would be gratefull. Just like I said I always used to activate my nvdia card with the steps I explained above. But now just a blackscreen appears if I start ubuntu in compatibility mode. If this wouldn't happen everything would be ok.

Comment: @futuress Can you try purging bumblebee (`sudo apt-get purge bumblebee`), install the nvidia driver (`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`) and reboot? If it fails again, please [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file by logging into a text console when boot fails and `cp /var/log/Xorg.0.log ~/`. After this, you can reboot and the file `Xorg.0.log` will contain your old logs.

Comment: Do you use the latest x-server from https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates ? I read that this is necessary for the most Optimus graphics cards.

Answer (score 1):

Now I think I solved my problem. I did everything like I said above. I reinstalled my nvidia divers like  Lekensteyn said, thanks for the advise. From now on it was very easy. I just have to type optirun  to start a programm with my nvidia G210m card. In glxspheres I get with the intel card 30fps and with the nvida card at least 100fps. I do think this is better than my last solution in ubuntu 11.10 with just running the nvidia card. Now I save battery life and if I want to play or if I need the card for othter programms I can use it with optirun.

Step by step:

1) deinstall the current nvidia divers ( sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current )

2) install bumblebee ( sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable )

3) reboot

4) reinstall the current nvidia drivers ( sudo apt-get install nvidia-current )

5) reboot

6) use optirun to start programms with the nvida card ( example: optirun glxsphere )